# Where can I find list of target selectors, ones that go after @a, @p etc in Minecraft Bedrock

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Browsing various forums and tutorials I was able to identify

position: x, y, z
game mode: m
minimum and max radius from an entity: r and rm
and that’s about it.

eg. `/gamemode a @a[m=!a,x=547,y=64,z=118,r=10]`
(will set the gamemode of a player to Adventure when their coming close to certain location)

Is there any official list of all possible parameters? I am most interested in testing the state entity such as sleeping and also players permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your one-stop go-to for all the information you will ever need about commands and more is the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/). The information provided is primarily for Java Edition, but the Bedrock Edition information is mixed in there, if you're willing to find it.

[This page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors) shows everything you need to know about target selectors. It shows each argument and what it does, plus some helpful hints and tips.

What's really handy is the table on the right side of the page, which I've screenshotted below. It is a list of all the target selector arguments, and you can read the main article for detailed information.

[image: Summary Table]

Unfortunately, your two requests (sleeping/not sleeping, permissions) are not available.

Have fun on your research!

Comment: I find Minecraft Wiki extremely confusing due to fact that Java and Bedrock versions are all mixed up and not always labeled. Thank you for the link it is most appreciated.